# mysqli_error doesn't work if xdebug breakpoint is hit

Tags: php, mysqli, xdebug

When I try to use `mysqli_error` during an xdebug session, and I hit a breakpoint, `mysqli_error` always returns "" (an empty string).
 The same exact PHP code will output an error if I do not hit a breakpoint.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM GOOOOOOO ";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql_conn2,$qry);
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "error: " . mysqli_error($mysql_conn2);
        die;
    }
```

Output without a breakpoint hit:

> error: database.gooooooo doesn't exist

Output with a breakpoint hit:

> error:

Does anyone know what causes this? Makes developing with xdebug kind of annoying to say the least.

I'm running php 5.5.19 and mysql 5.6.36

Comment: It looks for a database called GOOOOOOO but you want to select records from a table with this name. You must first select a database as a parameter in order to do a query or what is inside the mysql_conn2?

Comment: I'm selecting a database when the connection is created. Again, this query runs fine both from a mysql client and from this php code...unless you hit a breakpoint during execution. The breakpoint doesn't have to even be in the same file.

Comment: same issue, mysqli_error return empty string

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your php.ini:

```
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1
xdebug.force_error_reporting = 1
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1
```